# CSS - align element to the right of a centered div without overlapping/absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

So I'm sure this question has been asked before but I couldn't figure this out looking through the answers. 
I have a div that is centered with a max width of 900px. I want another small div to the right of it, but I don't want it to push the centered div to the left/cause other havoc. I managed to do this by using absolute positioning on the element I want to the right and pushing it down by padding it to the top, but I don't like this solution as I feel that I shouldn't have to pad it to get it where I want it, and if I shrink the window on my huge screen the text in the absolutely positioned element overlaps my centered element. The centered element is an image, and I would like for the right aligned element to be aligned horizontally with the top edge of the image. This is what my classes look like(Image is the element I want in the center, info is the one I want to the right):

```
.image {
    max-width: 900px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
}
#info{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10em;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks and sorry if this is a redundant question. 
EDIT: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xmQ6/

Answer (score 1):

Without a fiddle I can't be sure, but it sounds like inline-block would do just what you are asking.  Make both your centered div and the one to the right of it inline-blocks with vertical-align set to top and they will align next to each other, if there is horizontal room, otherwise they will wrap to the next line and stack.

```
.image, #info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

For this to work, they must be siblings and #info must come second in the DOM

```
<div class="image">...</div>
<div id="#info">...</div>
```

Comment: Got rid of my <article> and <section> tags, they were just in the way. I tried this but it isn't working, the center div gets pushed to the left. I have the margin right and left set to auto on it, is there any way to force it to center?

Comment: You can set text-align: center on its parent (possibly the body tag) which will center them together when there is room, or center them both when stacked.  If you want the image always centered and the aside not to change the centering then you'll need a wrapper object with some other positioning alternatives instead of inline-block.  http://jsfiddle.net/HEakE/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use CSS for the item on the right. In the HTML code, you can just use

```
<div align="right">
  INSERT YOUR #INFO HERE
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid

Comment: sorry, that was right off the top of my head. I will update now.

Comment: <div id="#info" align="right">...</div>

Use this directly. CSS isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this DEMO I created for you.
May be you can make it simpler if you tweak it

[DEMO is here](http://jsfiddle.net/95b6P/)

```
Give it a try
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figgered this out but my solution requires flexbox, [this](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) is the guide I used and pretty much that exact setup. Don't know why this is so difficult considering tons of sites have layouts like this. Either that or I'm really stupid, most likely the latter based on experience. Thanks everyone for your help.